# 3x2 between subjects design

Tags: spss, experiment-design

I have a research design where I have two IV's. One is processing type (high and low) and the other one is word load (small, medium and large). I am trying to figure out how to analyze this set. I first thought of creating two factors for two IV's where one IV is coded 0 / 1 and the second one is coded as 0/1/2 and then using SPSS Univariate analysis. I'm not sure if that is right. Another way I was thinking is creating three groups for the three IV levels and coding each as 0/1, but I don't know what type of analysis should I do then. I am checking for both main effects and interactions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to see whether there are main effects and interactions, one option to analyse this type of data set is to use ANOVA. It is certainly possible to do with SPSS, for example there is a tutorial here: 
https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/two-way-anova-using-spss-statistics.php